# Terminal server without audio card. Is virtual sound over rdp connections possible?

Tags: windows-server-2016, rdp, terminal-server, audio

I have a terminal server that is windows 2016. When I open sound in the botton right, it states that there are no devices that support sound (device manager doesn't show anything for sound either).

A few posts from close to 10 years ago discussed a Microsoft RDP Audio driver but I have been unable to locate this.

Are there any options to allow sound over the RDP connection without an actual audio card installed on the server? Something like a virtual sound driver of sorts?

I have found Scream but that sends the audio out over a multicast stream. I need to be able to connect to the host over RDP and hear sound. Any solutions for this problem or go buy an audio card? Thanks!

Comment: https://bitlaunch.io/blog/how-to-enable-remote-audio-microphone-remote-desktop/

Comment: @joeqwerty that steps were accomplished already. I also enabled the GPO for audio redirection. When I open sound playback/recording both state "No audio devices are installed". Windows audio service is running and set to automatic startup.